# File disappears after uploading it to a FTP path through network drive

Tags: windows-7, ftp

I am using Window 7 professional OS. I have configured a network drive to an FTP location. Mysteriously, whenever I copy an excel file onto that drive, it disappears withing minutes. I have confirmed that there is no clean up going on in that ftp location. Can anyone explain the reason behind this weird behavior?

Comment: Have you tried logging into the FTP site using an FTP client, to see if in fact the file is still there, or if it has been deleted?

Comment: No but I have tried this - When I try to copy the file again after 5 minutes, I am allowed to, but when I try to do it immediately, I am prompted that the file already exists. I do not see any other file in the location(and have no reason to believe that there are other files).

Comment: It sounds like something is deleting the file from the FTP server after a few minutes.  When you say, 'I have confirmed that there is no clean up going on in that ftp location', how have you confirmed this?  Is it possible that another client is remotely connecting to this same FTP site and deleting the file?  To solve this, I would try copying the same file to the FTP site using an FTP client (not via your network drive which is mapped to the FTP site), and see if the same thing happens.  This should help you isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just spoke with the n/w team. Actually a scheduler, which was running every minute, renames the incoming file.